# An example of a noetherian ring in which the integral closure of a finite extension of its field of fractions is not noetherian

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra

Similar to another question I posted. Does anyone know of an example of a noetherian ring in which the integral closure of a finite extension of it's field of fractions is not noetherian.

Comment: you mean noetherian domain, right?

Comment: Do you insist that the extension is non-trivial? Nagata (Local Rings, Appendix, Ex.5) gives an example where the integral closure (in the field of fractions) is nonnoetherian. 


Comment: Although this isn't what you asked for, you may also want to check out Akizuki's counterexample (1935) of a local Noetherian domain $A$ whose integral closure inside its own field of fractions isn't a finitely generated $A$-module. You can find a modern account of this counterexample here: http://arxiv.org/PS_cache/alg-geom/pdf/9503/9503017v1.pdf .

Comment: yes noetherian domain